# Cross account access to AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, external-dns

I have access to two AWS accounts, training and staging. Staging account holds all hosted zones, IAM roles; I want to grant access to training account so it can access a resource in Route53. I have created an IAM policy as below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ListHostedZones",
        "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I created an IAM role and attached above policy using "Another AWS account" option inserting training account ID, but I am still not able to list any hosted zones.

I am not sure what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: "I am still not able to list any hosted zones" - how exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: I tried in two ways, using CLI and web console

Comment: I mean how? How did you assume the role you've created, what errors did you get exactly?

Comment: I am assuming the role in the trusted account (training). Now I am able to see hosted zones when I switch role through web console but with CLI I am still not able to list hosted zones.

Comment: This is the tutorial that I am following
 https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md